# Meaning of "at it again"

Tags: meaning-in-context

The [Astoria Ledger](http://www.thx-trailer.com/replica/goonies/newspaper2/newspaper2.htm), from [The Goonies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Goonies), titled: *Fratelli's at it again*

What is the meaning of *(they are) `at it again`* in that context? Back at work, out of jail or another meaning?

Comment: "Damn daniel! Back at it with the white vans." (http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/at+it+again). They were probably just doing some mischievous deeds as soon as they got out. Not sure if you can consider this "work" though.

Comment: So does the newspaper title allude to their escape? A kind of _Fratelli's escaped once again_? Or more like: _Fratelli's at work once again_? : )

Comment: The German description about the ledger says they escaped, yes. Moreover, since the Goonies encounter them during the film, it's safe to say that they did, how else would they meet them outside of prison? The title simply means that they escaped and are already doing bad deeds, like the criminals they are. A previous edition of the newspaper probably covered their escape, and now they are reporting their new crimes in this issue, not their escape.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hard to tell without context. "At it again" means "doing some activity again which I dislike or object to", but whether it's criminal, underhand, noisy, offensive, or otherwise annoying is not specified.

Comment: Interesting! I'm trying to think of a context where "at it again" might refer to something positive rather than negative, but I'm having a hard time doing so. _Those Cub Scouts! At it again with their good deeds...._ The phrase does seem to imply some kind of annoyance somehow.

Comment: @J.R. There are ironic uses, but basically it is always disapproving.